# how to filter by cn component in ldapsearch?

Tags: search, active-directory, ldap

I am querying an Active Directory to gather the list of people having a given manager. The following search works fine:

```
$ ldapsearch "cn=John Doe" manager

dn: CN=John Doe,...
manager: CN=The Boss,...
```

What I would like is to have the right syntax to search for all people reporting to `The Boss`, something like

```
$ ldpasearch "<manager's cn is The Boss>" cn
```

which would return a list, including `cn=John Doe` (among others)

What is the correct syntax for such filter?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to filter on the `manager` attribute. However, you'll need to use the full distinguished name of the manager in the filter. For example:

`ldapsearch "manager=cn=John Doe,cn=users,dc=domain,dc=name" 1.1`

Comment: Thank you! I tried various things but not the full `dn`. It works perfectly.